# spring-kafka application.properties configuration for JAAS/SASL not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

**Use Case:**
I am using Spring Boot `2.2.5.RELEASE` and `Kafka 2.4.1`
JAAS/SASL configurations are done properly on Kafka/ZooKeeper as topics are created without issue with `kafka-topics.bat`

**Issue:**
When i start Spring Boot application, i immediately get the following errors:

kafka-server-start.bat console:
`INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)`

IDE console:
`WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=xxx, groupId=yyy] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected`

My `application.properties` configuration:

```
spring.kafka.jaas.enabled=true
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="spring_bO0t" password="i_am_a_spring_bO0t_user";
```

`kafka_server_jaas.conf`:

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="12345"
    user_admin="12345"
    user_spring_bO0t="i_am_a_spring_bO0t_user";
};
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I defined the properties in the wrong place i.e in `application.properties`. As i have ProducerFactory & ConsumerFactory beans, those `application.properties` will be *ignored* by Spring Boot.

Configuring the same properties *in the beans definitions* resolved the issue, i.e move your properties **from** `application.properties` **to** where you define your beans.

Here's an example:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, String.format(
            "%s required username=\"%s\" " + "password=\"%s\";", PlainLoginModule.class.getName(), "username", "password"
    ));
        
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, String.format(
        "%s required username=\"%s\" " + "password=\"%s\";", PlainLoginModule.class.getName(), "username", "password"
    ));

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    
    configs.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    configs.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
    configs.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required " + 
                                    "username=username" + 
                                    "password=password;");
    
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```

Comment: Can also try with ScramLoginModule.class instead of PlainLoginModule.class. If still facing authentication error. As could be in your Kafka ScramLoginModule is configured.

Comment: "As i have ProducerFactory & ConsumerFactory beans, those application.properties will be ignored by Spring Boot"...Wonder if you found any reference to this in the docs which says the properties will be ignored? But it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The answer provided by @jumping_monkey is correct, however I didn't know where to put those configurations in `ProducerFactory` & `ConsumerFactory` beans, so I'll leave an example below for those who want to know:

-In your `ProducerConfig` or `ConsumerConfig` Beans respectively (Mine is named `generalMessageProducerFactory`):

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, GeneralMessageDto> generalMessageProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    configProps.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
    configProps.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='YOUR_KAFKA_CLUSTER_USERNAME'   password='YOUR_KAFKA_CLUSTER_PASSWORD';");
    configProps.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

And also in your `TopicConfiguration` Class in `kafkaAdmin` method:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configs.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
    configs.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='YOUR_KAFKA_CLUSTER_USERNAME'   password='YOUR_KAFKA_CLUSTER_PASSWORD';");
    configs.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```

Hope this was helpful guys!

Answer (score 4):

If you use spring you can **add 3 properties to your yaml** file.

```
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_URL:localhost:9092}
    properties:
      security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
      sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="${KAFKA_USER:user}" password="${KAFKA_PASSWORD:pass}";
```