# AWS MSK Spring Boot App Example Using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, aws-msk

I want to create a Spring Boot App that connect to AWS MSK using IAM and produces and consumes event i looked over the internet but was not able to find any good resources

Note: I have deployed my a demo app hello world app on AWS EKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a reference to a [client.properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html) file in the docs.

```
ssl.truststore.location=<PATH_TO_TRUST_STORE_FILE>
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

[Spring-Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties) uses the same attributes under `spring.kafka.properties`

Comment: Thanks. Regarding Spring, how do you know what's the specific prefix for them? `none`? `admin`? `consumer`? `producer`? `stream`?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka That depends which client you need to configure. Not all properties are available to each.

Comment: And specifically for the ones in the answer? Couldn't find the spring docs for them :(

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka You can mix them, so there is no common prefix. Some are [not needed to be properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.security.protocol) - `spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location`, `spring.kafka.security.protocol`, and others not listed there do, such as `spring.kafka.properties[sasl.mechanism]`, etc. You can also provide them in the Bean. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60826009/2308683